# Returning values from many tables as fields in one resultset

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query, which returns a set of results populated with values from another other table:

```
select  mjc,
    name,
    (SELECT TOP 1 pageID FROM page WHERE mjc = 'ABC' ORDER BY createdOn DESC) AS LastCreatedId,
    (SELECT TOP 1 pageName FROM page WHERE mjc = 'ABC' ORDER BY createdOn DESC) AS LastCreatedName,
    (SELECT TOP 1 createdOn FROM page WHERE mjc = 'ABC' ORDER BY createdOn DESC) AS LastCreatedDate,
    (SELECT TOP 1 pageID FROM page WHERE mjc = 'ABC' ORDER BY modifiedOn DESC) AS LastEditedId,
    (SELECT TOP 1 pageName FROM page WHERE mjc = 'ABC' ORDER BY modifiedOn DESC) AS LastEditedName,
    (SELECT TOP 1 modifiedOn FROM page WHERE mjc = 'ABC' ORDER BY modifiedOn DESC) AS LastEditedDate,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM page WHERE mjc = 'ABC' AND published = 1) AS PublishedPages,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM page WHERE mjc = 'ABC' AND published = 0) AS UnpublishedPages
from mags
WHERE mjc IN ('ABC')
```

I was just wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this, by using joins for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can somewhat optimise your subqueries. These projections here:

```
(SELECT TOP 1 pageID FROM page WHERE mjc = 'ABC' ORDER BY createdOn DESC),
(SELECT TOP 1 pageName FROM page WHERE mjc = 'ABC' ORDER BY createdOn DESC),
(SELECT TOP 1 createdOn FROM page WHERE mjc = 'ABC' ORDER BY createdOn DESC),
```

Could also be re-written like this:

```
SELECT t.pageID AS LastCreatedId, 
       t.pageName AS LastCreatedName, 
       t.createdOn AS LastCreatedDate
FROM (SELECT TOP 1 pageID, pageName, createdOn
      FROM page where mjc = 'ABC' ORDER BY createdOn DESC) t
```

Or in the greater context

```
SELECT
    mjc,
    name,
    t.pageID AS LastCreatedId, 
    t.pageName AS LastCreatedName, 
    t.createdOn AS LastCreatedDate
FROM mags,
    (SELECT TOP 1 pageID, pageName, createdOn
     FROM page where mjc = 'ABC' ORDER BY createdOn DESC) t
WHERE mjc IN ('ABC')
```

That would allow for avoiding to run the same subquery 3 times. The same optimisation can be done for `LastEditedId, LastEditedName, LastEditedDate`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
select m.mjc,
       m.name,
       s.*
from mags m
join 
(select mjc,
        max(case when cr_rn = 1 then pageID end) LastCreatedId,
        max(case when cr_rn = 1 then pageName end) LastCreatedName,
        max(case when cr_rn = 1 then createdOn end) LastCreatedDate,
        max(case when mo_rn = 1 then pageID end) LastEditedId,
        max(case when mo_rn = 1 then pageName end) LastEditedName,
        max(case when mo_rn = 1 then modifiedOn end) LastEditedDate,
        sum(case published when 1 then 1 else 0 end) PublishedPages,
        sum(case published when 0 then 1 else 0 end) UnpublishedPages
 from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (order by createdOn desc) cr_rn,
             row_number() over (order by modifiedOn desc) mo_rn,
       from page where mjc = 'ABC') pa
 group by mjc) s
on m.mjc=s.mjc
WHERE m.mjc IN ('ABC')
```

- for a single access of page. If you want to select multiple mjc values, add `partition by mjc` to the `over` clauses of the row_number fields.

Comment: Jeez, that's probably the optimal solution, yet not so readable :-) too bad, SQL Server doesn't support the `FIRST_VALUE()` window function...

Answer (score 1):

I thought it would be something like this 
but I'm not sure it will give you same results.
I would tune it if I saw results of course. But just as an example:

---

```
select top 1 m.mjc,m.name,
       p.pageID,p.pageName,p.createdOn,
       p1.pageID,p1.pageName,p1.modifiedOn,
       count(p.*),count(p1.*)
       from mags m
inner join page p
  on m.mjc=p.mjc
inner join page p1
  on m.mjc=p1.mjc
where m.mgc='ABC'
  and p.published=1 
  and p1.published=0
group by 
  m.mjc,m.name,
  p.pageID,p.pageName,
  p.createdOn,p1.pageID,p1.pageName,p1.modifiedOn
order by p.createdOn desc,p1.modifiedOn desc
```

---

and I think you can use `max()` also  to get to your last `modifiedOn` and `createdOn`
instead of using two queries.

hope it helps abit